# How do I sanitize a time stamp for use in a conditional index in a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a rails migration where I need to create a conditional index. The condition includes a timestamp like so:

```
class IndexCreatedAtOnNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :notes, :created_at, where: "state = 'active' AND created_at >= #{200.days.ago}"
  end
end
```

However normally you would not put a timestamp straight into a string query in rails, instead you would do: `Note.where("created_at >= ?", 200.days.ago)` to get things escaped the right way with timezones and everything. How do I do that in my migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when use `#{value}` then the value will be called `to_s` on it to be converted to string the thing you miss here is to surround the date with single quotes and the `to_s` will be called for you on the date but you actually don't want `to_s` what you exactly want is calling `.to_formatted_s(:db)`:

```
add_index :notes, :created_at, where: "state = 'active' AND created_at >= '#{200.days.ago.to_formatted_s(:db)}'"
```

Comment: Just to mention [`to_formatted_s`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/RangeWithFormat.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) is actually an alias for `to_s`.